# Adding a script JS to my angular7 project

Tags: javascript, angular, installation, angular7, lib

For my project I need to install the "Loadingbar.js" lib to one of my pages (which you can find here: https://loading.io/progress/).
I did paste the CSS in my global "style.css" file.

So, first, I just tried to put the `<script></script>` in my index:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/loading-bar.js"></script>
```

It worked for few hours, and now it does not work anymore. So I tried everything: I tried to put the `<script>` everywhere on each line of my index.html or even in the html of my page, in the body, under the body, under the `<app-root></app-root>`... nothing worked.

Also, the Angular project is sometime trolling me: the js is loaded once very rarely. If I refresh the page without changing anything- it does not work anymore.

I tried to add "defer" to the `<script></script>`.

I tried to wait document ready, I tried the setTimeout, but it never worked.

I tried to add the path to the script in "angular.json", didn't work.

What can I do to make this work? How do I add JS lib to an angular project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should know is that in angular applications it's better to use `npm` dependency of any library if possible. If this is not possible and you need to use external js files, you can follow these steps:

1. First, put your js inside the `node_modules` folder. eg: `node_modules/test-lib/loading-bar.js`
2. Inside your `app.module.ts`, you can put this line at top of the file:

   `import test-lib/loading-bar.js`(without `node_modules`)

Comment: Thanks, but if I use that, I can't push my project on Git because the node_module folder isn't pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Loading.io links their library to their GitHub account.

They offer an Angular example here: 
https://github.com/loadingio/angular-loading-bar

It looks like the best approach is to install the library via npm or yarn.

Comment: Thanks, the library is not working, some imports arn't true like the "ldBar" import